# Router Child component not loading

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

This is my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PrimaryTestComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    DentistProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    JsonpModule,
    RouterModule,
    ClarityModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
                           { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
                           { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
                           { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
                           { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, children: [{path:'result/:name', component: DentistProfileComponent}
                           ]}
                         ])
  ],
  providers: [
    PrimaryTestService,
    SearchService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

this is how I call my route from  my search component's html:

```
<clr-dg-row *ngFor="let dentist of dentists">
        <clr-dg-cell>{{dentist.firstName}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{dentist.lastName}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{dentist.city}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{dentist.type}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell [routerLink]="['result',dentist.firstName]">View Profile</clr-dg-cell>
      </clr-dg-row>
```

and this is my dentist-profile.component.ts that I want to load on the click event

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dentist-profile',
  templateUrl: './dentist-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dentist-profile.component.css'],
  providers: [DentistProfileService]
})
export class DentistProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  id;
  constructor(private _Activatedroute:ActivatedRoute,
              private _router:Router){
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this._Activatedroute.snapshot.params['id'];
  }
}
```

The problem is that on click, the url is changing, but my pentist-profile component is not being loaded. I want it to replace it's parent component (i.e. SearchComponent), but it doesn't even appear to load in the first place. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

btw just to give you an idea, this is my main.component.html:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <header class="header header-6">
    Dentists Appointment System
  </header>
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    <a routerLink="/search" routerLinkActive="active">SEARCH</a>
    <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
    <a routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active">Register</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

for now it's just a div to test it out
dentist-profile.component.html

```
<div>IT WORKS</div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No, no errors in the console..

Comment: Are you sure the routerLink can be used like that? I've only ever seen it applied on an anchor. Could you just try this inside the cell <a [routerLink]="['result',dentist.firstName]">View Profile</a>

Comment: I tried it like this too, but it didn't work either. It actually reroutes me, since I see that the url changes to http://localhost:4200/search/result/Jane for example, but the component is not displayed.. No errors whatsoever.

Comment: Then the problem is your DentistProfileComponent. You didn't post the template so I'm not sure what it's supposed to look like, but could you just log something in the ngOnInit hook just to see if it's actually being initialized.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. In the routing, the path variable is name path:'result/:name', yet in the component, you're trying to access a variable "id", so that's going to return undefined.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me. Sadly that didn't fix the problem after I changed the variable to name, and also I'm not even trying to bind the variable in my html, i\m displaying only a div in the template of the component. I updated my question with the component and the respective html template

Comment: So if you try to log something?